# Korean and Japanese visa needed for travelling?

Tags: japan, south-korea

I'm a Philippine passport holder who is currently working in Germany. I already have a Residence Permit here in Germany.

I want to travel to Japan for a week, then another week going to Korea.
Do I need to get Japanese and Korean visa for travelling purposes?

Answer (score 1):

For Japan:

> Visa Requirements. UK, AUS, NZ, USA and CAN passport holders do not require a visa at present to enter Japan for touristic purposes for a stay of up to 90 days. ... Please double-check all visa requirements with the Japan embassy at least one month before travel as the above is intended as a guide.

You should check with the Japan embassy but as you do not hold any compatible passport you most likely need a visa.

South Korea:

> Visa Requirements for Philippine Passport Holders – South Korea (Republic of Korea) ... Citizens of many countries are allowed to stay for 3 months with proper visa documents

Answer (score 0):

According to [traveldoc.aero](https://www.traveldoc.aero), you will require a visa to visit Japan.

Per the same source, a visa is not required if your travel in Korea is to Jeju, will last no more than 30 days, and will include departure to a 3rd country (i.e. Japan -> Jeju -> Germany, but not Japan -> Jeju -> Japan or Japan -> Jeju -> Seoul -> Germany).